# Symfony REST bundle: add date to QueryParam requirements

Tags: php, regex, symfony, datetime

How would you require a valid [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) string inside Symfony's REST bundle's @QueryParam annotation?

I have this now:

`@QueryParam(name="createdFrom", requirements="2016-05-18T12:00:00+0000")`

I would like to use a regex that represents a [valid date time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) format.

Comment: Truely validating a date by regex is a nigh impossible task, when you consider leap years and the myriad of different possibe date formats. I don't know symfony, but doesn't it offer a way to require a certain predefined data format instead of a regex?

Comment: You are right: the best approach is to require a string and then check if I can create a valid date with it using `DateTime(string)`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way:

```
@QueryParam(name="createdFrom", nullable=false, requirements="(19|20)[0-9][0-9]-(0[0-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|([12][0-9]|3[01]))T([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]?[+|-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]")
```

Should work fine.

This above regex works for: **2016-05-18T12:00:00+0000**

This site you can use to test your regex: http://www.regexpal.com/1966

In this site has some samples of regex date: http://www.regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=datetime&c=0&m=0&ps=20&p=2

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

else :

```
/**
 * @Route("/blog/archive/{start}/{end}")
 * @ParamConverter("start", options={"format": "Y-m-d"})
 * @ParamConverter("end", options={"format": "Y-m-d"})
 */
public function archiveAction(\DateTime $start, \DateTime $end)
```